# RabbitMQ consumer can't convert message from queue : Failed to convert message

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I have a spring boot microservice that consume and produce messages to RabbitMQ at the same time, when I send (produce) messages to the exchange -> queue it all works fine, but when I try to consume from different queue and different type of message I receive an error as you can see below, in order to fix the problem I have to remove the messageConverter bean from the rabbitMQ eventProducerConfig file, but with doing that I will not be able to send messages to the queue because the message that Im sending is an object did anyone had the same issue before :

***the eventProducerConfig***

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class EventProducerConfig {


    @Bean
    public Queue notificationQueue() {
        return new Queue("notification", true);
    }



    @Bean
    Binding notificationBinding(Queue notificationQueue, DirectExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(notificationQueue()).to(exchange).with("notification.*");
    }
    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpTemplate amqpRabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageConverter messageConverter) {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }
}
```

***ConsumerConfig***

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class EventConsumerConfig {
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
        connectionFactory.setUsername("guest");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("guest");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue fileQueue() {
        return new Queue("file", true);
    }

    @Bean
    DirectExchange exchange() {
        return new DirectExchange("AppExchange");
    }

    @Bean
    Binding fileBinding(Queue fileQueue, DirectExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(fileQueue()).to(exchange).with("file.*");
    }

 

}
```

***Method that consume files***

```
 @RabbitListener(queues = {"file"})
    public void consumeFile(@Payload String fileBody){
        try {
            System.out.println(fileBody);
            
            FileQueueDTO fileQueueDTO = objectMapper.readValue(fileBody, FileQueueDTO.class);
            }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

***Error message***

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Failed to convert message
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:158) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1718) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1637) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1625) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1616) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListenerAndHandleException(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1561) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.lambda$executeListener$8(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1540) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:492) ~[micrometer-observation-1.10.4.jar:1.10.4]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1540) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1001) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:948) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1326) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1232) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Failed to convert Message content
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.doFromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:367) ~[spring-amqp-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:321) ~[spring-amqp-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:304) ~[spring-amqp-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.extractMessage(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:342) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter$MessagingMessageConverterAdapter.extractPayload(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:371) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.fromMessage(MessagingMessageConverter.java:132) ~[spring-amqp-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.toMessagingMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:244) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:148) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.String` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
 at [Source: (String)"{
"owner":"email@gmail.com",
"file":"C:\\Users\\"
}"; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1746) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1520) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1425) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.extractScalarFromObject(DeserializationContext.java:937) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._parseString(StdDeserializer.java:1421) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:48) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:11) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4730) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3677) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.convertBytesToObject(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:428) ~[spring-amqp-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.convertContent(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:395) ~[spring-amqp-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.doFromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:364) ~[spring-amqp-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    ... 20 common frames omitted

2023-05-30T23:00:39.680+01:00  WARN 4244 --- [ntContainer#0-1] ingErrorHandler$DefaultExceptionStrategy : Fatal message conversion error; message rejected; it will be dropped or routed to a dead letter exchange, if so configured: (Body:'[B@1b9db0e9(byte[54])' MessageProperties [headers={}, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=file, deliveryTag=4, consumerTag=amq.ctag-uHKbO7tOLUzhG1lG6E4f8Q, consumerQueue=file])
2023-05-30T23:00:39.680+01:00 ERROR 4244 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed, and the error handler threw an exception

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: Error Handler converted exception to fatal
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.handleError(ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.java:146) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeErrorHandler(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1509) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.handleListenerException(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1806) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListenerAndHandleException(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1582) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.lambda$executeListener$8(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1540) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:492) ~[micrometer-observation-1.10.4.jar:1.10.4]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1540) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1001) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:948) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1326) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1232) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Failed to convert message
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:158) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1718) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1637) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1625) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1616) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListenerAndHandleException(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1561) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Failed to convert Message content
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.doFromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:367) ~[spring-amqp-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:321) ~[spring-amqp-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:304) ~[spring-amqp-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.extractMessage(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:342) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter$MessagingMessageConverterAdapter.extractPayload(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:371) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.fromMessage(MessagingMessageConverter.java:132) ~[spring-amqp-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.toMessagingMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:244) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:148) ~[spring-rabbit-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.String` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
 at [Source: (String)"{
"owner":"email@gmail.com",
"file":"C:\\Users\\"
}"; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1746) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1520) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1425) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.extractScalarFromObject(DeserializationContext.java:937) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._parseString(StdDeserializer.java:1421) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:48) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:11) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4730) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3677) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.convertBytesToObject(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:428) ~[spring-amqp-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.convertContent(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:395) ~[spring-amqp-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.doFromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:364) ~[spring-amqp-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you put an example of Json file when you want to invoke the consumer ?

Comment: You can change you method like this : public void consumeFile(@Payload FileQueueDTO fileBody) and log the object without this block of code : FileQueueDTO fileQueueDTO = objectMapper.readValue(fileBody, FileQueueDTO.class);

Comment: @skillup still the same problem, even if I just want to log the value of the payload it returns the same error, I think the problem is wth the message converter, is there anyway to disable the message converter from only this method because as I mentionned I need the message converter in the producer

Comment: Solved: I removed the @Payload and changed the parameter type from (String fileBody) to (Message fieBody) now I have access to the raw message body and I can deserialize it using any JSON library.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

I removed the `@Payload` and changed the parameter type from `String fileBody` to `Message fileBody` now I have access to the raw message body and I can deserialize it using any JSON library.